# How to add custom style to react react-pagination-table header

Tags: reactjs

I want add custom style to Pagination table header, I am using below code

```
<TablePagination
    className='table table-striped table-responsive-md dataTable tbl-list'
    headers={ ["ID", "Name", "Email", "Status" ] }
    data={ this.props.data }
    columns="id.Name.Email.Status."
    perPageItemCount={ 10 }
    totalCount={ 649 } 
    arrayOption={ [["size", 'all', ' ']] }
/>
```

In this code I've added some css class which working fine for table body and I want to add some css class for table headers also. How I will pass header css class ?

Comment: which pagination library are you using?

Comment: react-pagination-table

Comment: nd I followed this url https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pagination-table for reference in this link they have mentioned how to pass but it's not working form me "{className}__header"

Comment: have you tried props react-pagination-table__header={'yourClassName'} .

Comment: I've tried this 
className__header='bac-col' and react-pagination-table__header='bac-col' but it's not working